# Flash / Actionscript wheel

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript

**Hi,**

I have been asked to create a wheel for navigation similar to on the [Visit Provence](http://instantanes.visitprovence.com/?l=en/#/en/photos) website. However, I don't know where to start and my Googling effort have been unsuccessful - I guess that I am searching using the wrong terms.

It the the way that the wheel moves and interacts with the other segments around it that interests me.

I'd really appreciate any tutorials / help that anyone can share.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a complex problem you must divide it into simpler problems.

First, I suggest that you try to draw your wheel. Add the mouse-over effect. Then you need to create the background. This is a separate problem. Then you connect the two solutions that you have, preferably with a mouse event listener.

Comment: Thank you. That is sound advice. Is there any amazing tutorial that you can think of that could get me started?

Comment: @Shaun: No, tutorials are overrated and a waste of your time. Learn by experimenting and building on your own. Also, explore the ActionScript 3 Reference.